# C++ - How to print this correctly?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, tic-tac-toe

I'm programming a small game in C++ (Tic Tac Toe), and have a problem while printing the board.

Here's the code ("syntax.h" is a header file with functions such as print, println, input):

```
#include "syntax.h" // contains helpful functions such as "print" and "println" to shorten code

char board[3][3];
void print_board();

int main()
{
    print_board();
}
void print_board()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        println("-------");
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            print("|" + board[i][j] + " "); // ERROR - Cannot add two pointers
        }
        println("|");
    }
    println("-------");
    input();
}
```

`print` is a function in "syntax.h" that receives a string variable and prints it with `cout`, and then flushes the output buffer.

Now, I cannot print a string like above because it tells me I cannot add two pointers.

I understand why it happens, and thats because the "" in the print parameters are actually `char*` and not `string` variables, and I cannot add them together.

The problem is that I also don't want to make another print function call, and print all these 3 string in this same function call.

So how am I supposed to print this above without the error?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but I haven't seen `print` or `println` in C++.  Are these your functions?

Comment: Yes, they are. Please read the whole question next time, because I've written that they are my functions too many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
print("|" + board[i][j] + " ");
```

Try

```
print((std::string("|") + board[i][j] + " ").c_str())
```

std::string has an overloaded operator+ for concatenation. Don't forget to

```
#include <string>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use sprintf() function:

```
//print("|" + board[i][j] + " "); // ERROR - Cannot add two pointers 
char buffer[100];   
sprintf(buffer, "| %s ", board[i][j]);
print(buffer);
```

while if you want use the string type could do this:

```
//print("|" + board[i][j] + " "); // ERROR - Cannot add two pointers    
print(string("|") + string(board[i][j]) + string(" "));
```

Comment: OK, But isn't this a function from C? Can't I use C++ print functions and just print strings like this with the + signs (add them in the printing string parameters?)

Comment: sprintf is standard function for C and C++. It is declared in the  <stdio.h> header file. If you provide your implementation of the print I could try to change it for you.

Comment: It does work if I do `print(string("|") + board[i][j] + string(" "));`, but that's just too much to write for every time you print.

Comment: My implementation is pretty simple: the `print` function gets a string and then it prints it with `cout`. I just dislike the nature of `cout` that you have to use the `<<` signs because I'm used to functions with (), and the `<<` signs with `cout` are not as good IMO.

Comment: I posted a new implementation using the string type